# Webserver within another network

Tags: networking, webserver

I'm thinking of putting a small web server inside another network (in a shopping centre)

Can I do that without port forward the "first router" ?

The network has a router, connected to the Internet. Can I simply plugin a router AFTER the first router and port forward that one? Or how should I do?
The IP-address part is no problem (The server sends out the IP-address to a MySQL server)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method for you would be the port forwarding for both routers.

Internet <-> Router 1 <-> Router 2 <-> webserver

1. If you are are on the internet side you need both port forwarded. Router 1 forwards port 80 to Router 2. Router 2 forwards port 80 to webserver.
2. If you are connected to Router 1 directly. On the same subnet as Router 1. Then you only need to port forward router 2 port 80 to the webserver.